# Turning file reading for loops into list comprehensions

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

So I wrote some code that determines the 4 most common words in a text file and then finds all the words that occur 2% or more. My code works great so far. But I have to turn the for loops into list comprehensions.

So far I've tried:

```
percent_list = [word, freq in word_counts.most_common(total) if ((freq/total)*100) >= 2.0]
```

For the second for loop, (see the entire code below.) But it doesn't work. This seems a little long for a list comprehension because all the ones online seem a lot shorter.

Here's the entire program. There's two for-loops total.

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

STOP = ["the", "and", "in", "to", "a", "of", "at", "it", "but", "its","it's", "that", "was", "with", "as", "are", "i","this", "for", "if"]



word_counts = Counter()

with open("file.txt") as f:
  for token in f.read().split():
    if token.lower() not in STOP:
      word_counts[token.lower()] += 1

  print( word_counts.most_common(4),  ":")  


total = sum(word_counts.values())

print("\nWords that occur for 2% or more are: ")
for word, freq in word_counts.most_common(total):
  if ((freq/total)*100) >= 2.0:
    print("\n {} ".format(word))
```

Comment: `...I have to turn the for loops into list comprehensions.` If your for loops work leave them be.

Comment: Why you have to turn for loops in list comprehension? They aren't the same thing. List comprehension will hold values in memory while loops may not

Comment: Also your for loop is very imperative, list comprehension are better for defining lists in an declarative way, but you aren't building a list you are incrementing a value

Answer (score 1):

I think this should fix your problem. It will return a list of tuples of word and frequencies.

```
percent_list = [(word, freq) for word,freq in word_counts.most_common(total) if ((freq/total)*100) >= 2.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

With most simple comprehensions, we can first look at how they would look like when unrolled.

In general, a `list` comprehension of this form:

```
result = []
for element in source:
    if predicate(element):
        result.append(modify(element))
```

Can be reduced to:

```
result = [modify(element) for element in source if predicate(element)]
```

The problem here is that we are iterating over *two* elements at once, since the equivalent of `source` is `word_counts(most_common).total`.

We can therefore write our unrolled `for` loop in this way:

```
result = []
for word, freq in word_counts.most_common(total):
    if ((freq / total) * 100) >= 2:
        result.append((word, freq))
```

Note the extra pair of parentheses around `word, freq`; that forms a `tuple`, which is *one* element. Remember that you can only add one element at a time to a `list` through `append`.

This gives us the following comprehension:

```
[(word, freq) 
 for word, freq in word_counts.most_common(total) 
 if ((freq / total) * 100) >= 2]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation! But for the first for loop in the code, how would you handle the "[token.lower()]" syntax in a comprehension. I'm now trying to turn that loop into a comprehension as well. Would that part not be included in the comprehension?

Comment: @KFate Well, that could be done in a `dict` comprehension, but the thing is that you're using a `Counter` object, which is meant more for iterative modification in a `for` loop, rather than declarative construction in a *comprehension*. If you wanted to do it with a comprehension, you should probably use a normal `dict`.